# How to remove audio from every .mp4 in a directory using Win-10 Pro cmd.exe?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

I have not been able to find an answer to this 'specific question' as it relates to Win-10 Pro. Some responses seem to address the 'general' question, however they almost always state/post they are using some other OS such as used on/with a Mac, or some flavor of Linux.

-- We need to remove all audio from a dir full of .mp4 files, while also preserving the original file.

Please explain the syntax/cmd offered\suggested. From that point we will compare with ffmpeg documentation to better understand.

Answer (score 0):

This post/answer is detailed for the new user. Here is a command that removes all sound from every filename ending with .mp4; as long as the files are in the same dir from which you ran the command. The command has only been tested with our:

--Win-10 Pro/OS Build 19041.572.
To find your Win-10 Pro build, open cmd.exe, when the prompt is ready, type: ver

--cmd.exe, current version is 10.0.119041.546
To find the current version of your cmd.exe, using the 'Windows Explorer', not to be confused with 'Internet Explorer', navigate to C:\Windows\System32 scroll-down to the icon labeled cmd.exe. Right-click, then left-click the details tab.

THE COMMAND:
C:\your_prompt>for /F %i in ('dir /b *.mp4'); do ffmpeg -i %i -c:v copy -an %i_noSnd.mp4

The result(s) will be:
-- The original file is preserved
-- A duplicate file (for each original) is created (in the same directory) as the original, --with _noSnd.mp4 appended.

This should get you, the unseasoned user, started with batch removal of 'all' audio from video filenames ending in .mp4 which reside in the same dir from where you ran the cmd provided above.